# Is this DropDownListFor default behavior in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I noticed below behaviour and wonder why “Model.CountryList” is null at POST? If this the default MVC behaviour or we have any to get rid of that?

**Model**

```
public class CountryMaster
{
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public int SelectedCountry { get; set; }
    public List<CountryMaster> CountryList { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Demo.Web.ViewModels.HomeViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCountry, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "CountryCode", "CountryName"), "---SELECT COUNTRY---" new { @class = "chosen", @onchange = "this.form.action='/Home/Index'; this.form.submit(); " })
```

**Note –** above DDL is bind with both properties, “SelectedCountry” & “CountryList”.

**Controller**

In “Index”, HttpGet method, getting the “CountryList” with some database hit,

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
     **//get all countries and fill “CountryList”**
        homeViewModel.CountryList = _commonService.GetCountriesList();
        return View(homeViewModel);
    }
```

Now when we choose an item in DDL and hit the post then in “Index”, HttpPost, the “SelectedCountry” is filled with some value, but the “CountryList” is NULL, WHY?

Please help understand me WHY the “CountryList” is NULL and is there any way to persist the same?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel homeViewModel)
    {  
     /**/ selectçountryValue = 2**
        var selectçountryValue = homeViewModel.SelectedCountry;
     **// CountryListAtPost = null**
        var CountryListAtPost = homeViewModel.CountryList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of HttpPost, View returns all the FormCollection to the controller. So it always has the values that are stored in the form elements i.e textbox, dropdown or hidden fields.

In your case the homeViewModel must contains the value of SelectedCountry property because it is in form collection and associated with DropDown element, but CountryList is not associated with any elements that's why its returning null.

To return the collection from view to controller find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218602/how-do-i-return-list-or-collection-to-controller-from-view-in-mvc-3) thread.

Good Luck !!

Comment: Thanks for giving me the reason (the form collection thing), but question is if we check above view code for binding dropdownlistfor, we used both properties 1. SelectedCountry & 2. CountryList , then why "countrylist"not in Form Collection?

Comment: As i said that in my answer that "countrylist" is not associated with any form elements

Comment: Ok...got it...thanks, but difficult to associate "countrylist" to any form element...may be hidden field help me?

Comment: Yes but not a single hidden. Follow the article that i have mentioned in my article.

Comment: @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountryList) makes available "countrylist" to Form Collection, but the count is zero :)

Comment: @user584018 a single hidden field wouldn't do the trick you need multiple. Find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218602/how-do-i-return-list-or-collection-to-controller-from-view-in-mvc-3) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Kundan, multiple Hidden fields will solve the issue,

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCountry, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "CountryCode", "CountryName"), "---SELECT COUNTRY---",
                                    new { @class = "chosen", @onchange = "this.form.action='/Home/Index'; this.form.submit(); " })
            @if (Model.CountryList != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.CountryList.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountryList[i].CountryCode) 
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountryList[i].CountryName)
                }
            }
```