# List to Controller from View in MVC 4 missing values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

After many years of getting a lot of great advice here, I finally have hit a wall teaching myself MVC4 ASP.net.

I used this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218602/how-do-i-return-list-or-collection-to-controller-from-view-in-mvc-3)  to pass a List of Type Class from my controller, to my view, and back to the controller..

```
public ActionResult SelectProducts()
{
    displayProductsList = db.Products.ToList();
    displayProductsList.ForEach(delegate(Product p)
    {
        //get list of recievables for the product
        GetReceivablesByProductId(p.ProductID).ForEach(delegate(Receivable r)
        {
            //Get count of items in inventory for each recievable                  
            p.CurrentInventory += this.CountItemsByReceivableID(r.RecievableID);
        });                
    });
    return View(FilterProductInventoryList(displayProductsList));
}
```

And here is my view code..

```
@model List<CarePac2.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SelectProducts";
}

<h2>SelectProducts</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table>
        @*row values*@
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Brand)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].ProductName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].UnitType)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].SalePrice)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].CurrentInventory)</td>
                <td>                  
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].OrderQuantity)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].OrderQuantity)
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        @*<input type="submit" value="Cancel" />*@
    </p>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Here the view show it has values for the List that was passed from controller to view..

Visually the view displays the data correctly (apparently i can't post an image of it until i have 10 reputation to post images)

when i hit submit and return to the controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult SelectProducts(List<Product> selectedProducts)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
     }
 }
```

The variable selectedProducts Is NOT NULL.  The list has 3 Product items in it, however, as you can see in the image below in the debugger, even though i have 3 product items, none of the values exist from when the List of Product was originally passed to the view...

for example (since i can't post images yet):

```
selectedProducts[0].ProductID=0
selectedProducts[0].ProductName=null
selectedProducts[1].ProductID=0
selectedProducts[1].ProductName=null
```

Comment: The only controls you generate are for property `OrderQuantity` so that is the only property of your model that will post. Add hidden input for the ID property (the other properties you should be getting from the database again if you need them)

Comment: If you want to post an image, just provide its url, and I'll add it.

Comment: you must be getting `OrderQuantity's` value right?

Comment: yes, the purpose is to display the products available, let the user enter how many they way, then when they click save, the controller on the back end adds the SalesOrder and WorkOrder entities to the DB, then adds the number of WorkOrderItems based on the order quantity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `@Html.HiddenFor()`:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ProductID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ProductName)
```

This will send the data back to the controller. This creates an `<input type="hidden">` that will be part of the form POST.

Comment: Ok, this works for getting the values back, as I break into my code my selectedProducts variable has three objects in the list, and each object is populated with values as it should be....this had a site effect though, when the view is displayed, all the items i changed form html.DisplayFor to html.HiddenFor are no longer visible on the view form.  All i see are the edit boxes for the Order Quanity.

Comment: You need them both. The HiddenFor created an <input> element which is always passed back to the controller action via the form post. The DisplayFor is just going to render it out as text and has nothing to do with tying back to your controller action. You could also just use @Model[i].Brand to render the value if you aren't using templates to render your values based on their data types.

Comment: Thank you very much, its now working as intended.  I'll take some time to learn more about the different htm.(tags) and what they do going forward.